# Как открыть illustrator из photoshop?

Tags: вёрстка, photoshop

Допустим имеется векторное изображение svg в макете psd.
Слои:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как настроить фотошоп, чтобы при клике по иконке открывался illustrator?
А сейчас при клике на иконку, показанную стрелкой, открывается браузер с svg-иконкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас стоит настройка в системе - отрывать файлы *.svg с помощью браузера. Попробуйте вне фотошопа *.svg "открыть с помощью...">выбрать другое приложение>выбрать иллюстратор, и проставить галочку "всегда использовать это приложение для открытия файлов"